# gradle snapshot not resolved in local repository when uniqueVersion=false

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

For my Android Library I'm using the "UploadArchives" task to deploy the AAR :

```
uploadArchives {
repositories.mavenDeployer {
    configuration = configurations.deployLibrary
    pom.groupId = groupId
    pom.artifactId = artifactId
    pom.version = version
    uniqueVersion = false
    repository(url: "${RemoteReleaseDest}")
    snapshotRepository(url: 'file://' + "${localReleaseDest}") { }
}
}
```

Where "RemoteReleaseDest" is a remote Repository and "localReleaseDest" point to my Local maven repository (C:/User/me/.m2.repository).

this work pretty well for release version ex: myaar:2.0.0 ( I can as well set the "RemoteReleaseDest" to my local .m2  repository to force to deploy the release on it.

Then when I configure the dependency in my android project like this :

```
compile 'mygroupId:myartefact:2.0.0'
```

the dependency is correctly resolved (even from my local repository).
but if I try with snaptshot :

```
compile 'mygroupId:myartefact:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

gradle cannot resolve the dependency. while in the gradle log I can see that it is seaching in my .m2 local repository.

But if I Upload the snapshot archives with the parameter :

```
uniqueVersion = true
```

the gradle can resolve the dependency !

The problem in this case is that every time I launch the task "uploadArchives" I will create new AAR, xml, md5 etc... files under the local SNAPSHOT directory.

**So why gradle cannot resolve the snapshot dependency when the snapshot is deployed with the param `uniqueVersion = false`and how can I manage this issue ?**